# Export of discussion notes from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to export discussion notes from Azure DevOps Work items like Task/Bug etc. Or is there a way in Azure DevOps to get a consolidated web view of discussion? Or can you suggest any extensions that help achieve this?

Checked Azure DevOps for getting the dump through query which did not work

Comment: Hey you could readout the information from a Work item over the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). If you want to export all item make a [List Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) request and loop all results to make `Get Work Item` request.

Answer (score 3):

Using the rest api below, you can get the comments records of multiple work items from the response body.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=5.1
```

[image]

But the flaw of this rest api is that it can't display all the comment records, only display the latest comment of this work item.

If you want to get all the comments of a work item, you need to use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get%20comments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) below. However, the drawback of this rest api is that it can only return all the comments of a work item, and cannot display the comments records of multiple work items.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/comments?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

[image]